# Scope by User and Non-scope by User

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is it possible to have the Integration User set to Non-scope by User and all other Users set to Scope by User OR do all Users need to have the same scope?

Answer (score 2):

This setting is made at the connection level. All users will share the same scope setting.  If you need to extend "or limit" the scope of data the Integrated User has access to, you can do this via profile and permission-set setting in Sales Cloud.

Note: automation, journeys and synchronized data extension run under the permissions of the Integration User.